# How do I catch 400 in the new form?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Prior to my Angular/Typescript upgrade, this form is always able to catch return code 400,

```
.subscribe
(
  good => { ... },
  bad => { ... }  // ok to catch 400
)
```

now it's deprecated, new form is

```
.subscribe
(
  {
    next: (good) => { ... },
    error: (bad) => { ... } // NOT catch code 400, etc.
  }
)
```

[image]

but it doesn't catch any response status 400, it just steps into the `good` part. There must be something I'm not doing right.

```
"@angular/cli": "~14.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2",
"typescript": "~4.7.4"
"rxjs": "~7.4.0"
```

Comment: Please show complete code and not just fragment. There is not enough here to answer the question. "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Because really at the end of the day you probably want to do something like this, but there's no way to answer definitively with the question in its current state. https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20210827-TestingFailingHttpRrequestsInAngular.html

Comment: angular http can observer the response. by default it observes the body. `this.http.get(url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(tap(resp => console.log(resp))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    tap(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('HTTP Error ' + response.status);
      }
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      // handle the error here
      console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      return of(null);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(response => {
    // handle the response here
    console.log('Received response:', response);
  });
```

In this code,Use tap operator to inspect the response and throw an error if the status code is not 200. After that `catchError` operator to handle the error in the `subscribe` method, where log the error and return an empty observable using the of operator.

This way, you can catch HTTP status codes, such as 400, and handle them appropriately in your code.